# creating physic with cannon.js in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, game-physics, physics, cannon.js

**I have been working on three.js and cannon.js**
I have been struggling with the cannon.js part, basically what is supposed to happen is it creates the usual. (scene, camera, renderer) then it creates a plane geometry that in the animate function it copies the position and rotation of the groundBody which from what I can tell the collision box and what has physics.

The problem I'm having though is that the mesh doesn't fall to the ground. From what i see there is no errors but I'm stuck with replit's built in console because my school blocked the actual console and replit's for some reason doesn't always give all errors only major game breaking ones.

**for those that aren't familiar with replit**, pressing "<>"
will show the code for all the different file such as index.html or css for those who want to see I for some reason

[project](https://replit.com/@OwenStritz/3js?v=1), main.js:

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { OrbitControls } from 'https://threejs.org/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';

import * as Cannon from 'https://unpkg.com/cannon/build/cannon.js';

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();

renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

const scene = new THREE.Scene();

const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
  45,
  window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
  0.1,
  1000
);

const orbit = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

camera.position.set(0, 20, -30);
orbit.update();

// ------------------------------------------------------------
const groundGeo = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(30, 30);
const groundMat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: 0xffffff,
  side: THREE.DoubleSide,
  wireframe: true
});
const groundMesh = new THREE.Mesh(groundGeo, groundMat);
scene.add(groundMesh);
// ------------------------------------------------------------

const world = new CANNON.World({
  gravity: new CANNON.Vec3(0, -9.81, 0)
});

const groundBody = new CANNON.Body({
  shape: new CANNON.Plane(),
  mass: 10
});
world.addBody(groundBody);

const timeStep = 1 / 60;

function animate() {
  world.step(timeStep);

  groundMesh.position.copy(groundBody.position);
  groundMesh.quaternion.copy(groundBody.quaternion);
  
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

renderer.setAnimationLoop(animate);

window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
})
```

Comment: This is a good starter: [crafting-a-dice-roller-with-three-js-and-cannon-es](https://tympanus.net/codrops/2023/01/25/crafting-a-dice-roller-with-three-js-and-cannon-es/)